# Set number limit to 2 decimals

Tags: sql-server, precision

I am having a problem creating a function for SQL server query in php or changing how the value output I get in index page where the result would be something like = 25.879999999999999 when I want it as 25.87

```
when ap.idproduct = 1 then cast(tr.PreviousBalance as float)/100 
else cast(tr.FinalBalance as float)/100 end as balance_before,
```

need float limited to 2 decimals or a function ( please explain how it is used as I kinda new to PHP)

Comment: What you want is [rounding](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+round+float)

Comment: do you mean https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php ? and how do I use it ?

Comment: `how do I use it`...well that's what the documentation is for. It explains what inputs the function expects and what it will output. And there are examples of usage too. So where are you stuck, having read that?

Comment: But...I've just noticed: it seems like what you've shown us in the question is actually SQL code, whereas your question is tagged with PHP. So I linked you to PHP solutions, but maybe what you actually need is a SQL solution. Please do tag your question accurately... see [ask] and also [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: oops, forgot to add that it is an SQL query in PHP

Comment: In that case you should do the same google search I linked you to in my first comment, but change "php" to whatever your SQL variant is (e.g. "mysql" or "SQL Server" or "Oracle" or whatever), and it should lead you to the correct SQL function. This really has nothing to do with PHP at all, so I removed the tag. Instead you should tag your DBMS in addition to the basic "sql" tag (as per that tag's blurb), because each SQL variant has different functions and syntax in many cases.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining as to my understanding I thought SQL variant does not matter   for SQL queries in PHP

Comment: Why wouldn't it? All PHP does is take whatever SQL code you write and send it to the database server. It then gets executed by the database engine. So it still needs to be valid code for that database variant. It doesn't matter whether you run the query from an IDE, or from PHP code, or the command-line, or whatever. It still gets executed by the database itself. PHP has no relevance here.

Comment: So if you're using MS SQL Server then I'd expect you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Ah okay my bad then, And sorry for asking but in the example of query statement above how do I use the ROUND function ?

Comment: You wrap it round the value / expression whose output you want to round. So I guess you want to round the result of `cast(tr.PreviousBalance as float)/100`, perhaps?

Comment: And maybe the result of `cast(tr.FinalBalance as float)/100` as well?

Comment: so it would be like `ROUND(cast(tr.FinalBalance as float)/100)`  ?

Comment: Why not simply try it and then you'll see if it works as you expect? But yes that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

FIX :

```
ROUND(cast(tr.PreviousBalance /100 as float), 4)
```

Wrapping cast in round